# Oracle will not allow me to continue no matter what I try

Tags: sql, oracle, function, select, group-by

Please help I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

```
select state, count(CID)
from customers
group by CID asc;
```

I'm trying to get the states in ascending order based on the number of unique CID's associated with it. I keep getting this error:

> ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression 00979. 00000 - "not a GROUP BY expression" *Cause: *Action: Error at Line: 2 Column: 3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've mixed ORDER BY and GROUP BY statements. The correct query should be something like this:

```
select state, count(CID)
from customers
group by state
ORDER BY 2 asc
```

---

And in order to get the count of unique CID, you need to add DISTINCT statement in COUNT function:

```
select state, count(DISTINCT CID)
from customers
group by state
ORDER BY 2 asc
```

Comment: Great, this worked. Just curious what "ORDER BY 2 asc" denotes?

Comment: @user2991463 It means order by second column ascending.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to order your resultset, you need to use the `order by` clause, as shown below.

Also, you want to `group by state` rathern than `by CID`.

```
select 
  state, 
  count(distinct CID) 
from 
  customers  
group by 
  state
order by 
  count(distinct CID) asc;
```

Since your question mentiones *unique CID's associated* (of which I am not 100% sure how this is to be interpreted), you might want to consider using `count(distinct CID)` instead of `count(CID)`.

Comment: Thanks but that's a no go. This is the error:

Comment: ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression
00979. 00000 -  "not a GROUP BY expression"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 2 Column: 3